# Error while mint NFT on Solana with Metaplex - erro: Failed to serialize or deserialize account data: Unknown

Tags: solana-program, metaplex, metaplex-js

**Describe the bug**
The error there is when I trying mintNft

**To Reproduce**

```
const metadataURI = 'https://metadata...'
const myWallet = new Metaplex.NodeWallet(walletKeyPair);
const connection = new Metaplex.Connection('devnet');
const txMasterMint = await Metaplex.actions.mintNFT({
      connection,
      wallet: myWallet,
      uri: metadataURI,
      maxSupply: 0,
    });
```

**Error**

````
This is a complete error message:
```shell
SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: Failed to serialize or deserialize account data: Unknown
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (/Users/jeff/web3/studies/solana/metaplex/nft-api/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:9088:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (/Users/jeff/web3/studies/solana/metaplex/nft-api/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:9054:20) {
  logs: [
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: InitializeMint',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 2967 of 1200000 compute units',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Error: BorshIoError',
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 4273 of 1197033 compute units',
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: Failed to serialize or deserialize account data: Unknown'
  ]
}
````

```
**Metaplex Version:**
- `"@metaplex/js": "^4.12.0"`

**Desktop (please complete the following information):**
 - OS: Mac air M1
```

Comment: Line 3 should be `Metaplex.connection('devnet')` . That may be the reason? Try making the change

Comment: I adding but I have same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The @metaplex/js version you are using is very outdated.

[Metaplex deprecated](https://twitter.com/metaplexstatus/status/1631464812361424897?s=46&t=m46WP-lQMQqfSK52SeWe2A) some instructions lately to regain space in the token metadata program.

The solution for you should be to upgrade to the newest @metaplex/js version which currently is 0.19.2